# Automagically create predicates that detect components of a sum type?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

What I mean is this:

```
data D = A Int | B String  -- A sum type.

isA, isB :: D -> Bool  -- Component predicates.
isA (A _) = True
isA _     = False
isB (B _) = True
isB _     = False
```

This is tedious to define. Surely there is a better way. And one way there is:

```
data D = A Int | B String deriving (Typeable, Data)

isA', isB' :: D -> Bool
isA' x = toConstr x == toConstr (A undefined)
isB' x = toConstr x == toConstr (B undefined)
```

But it requires me to provide an example value.

There is a trick that allows one to *"fold"* functions of any number of variables with an
*"inductive"* class, which lets us define a method that obtains a value from a constructor of any
arity:

```
class C a v where createValue :: a -> v
instance C b D => C (a -> b) D where createValue f = createValue (f undefined)
instance C D D where createValue = id

compareConstructor :: forall a v. (C a v, Data v) => v -> a -> Bool
compareConstructor x c = toConstr x == toConstr (createValue c :: v)
```

This is how it works:

```
data D = A Int | B String | C Bool Char deriving (Typeable, Data, Show)

λ compareConstructor (B "z") (C True)
False
λ compareConstructor (C True 'c') C
True
```

I like this solution, but I wonder if there is a more straightforward way to solve this simple,
everyday problem.

#### Motivation:

I have a list of values of type D, mostly filled with `A _`, and I need to find out whether a `B _` value occurs before `C _ _`. I can solve this problem by comparing two `findIndex` invocations, but I need to parametrize them appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GHC.Generics is another way.

You can use the [`is`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Extras.html#v:is) function from the lens library and [generic prisms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens-1.2.0.0/docs/Data-Generics-Sum-Constructors.html) from the generic-lens library to check whether a value starts with a given constructor `MyCon`:

```
is (_Ctor @"MyCon") myValue
  :: Bool
```

Compilable example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, TypeApplications, DataKinds #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Generics.Sum
import Control.Lens.Extras

data D = A Int | B String
  deriving Generic

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ is (_Ctor @"A") (A 0)   -- True
  print $ is (_Ctor @"A") (B "")  -- False
  print $ is (_Ctor @"B") (A 0)   -- False
  print $ is (_Ctor @"B") (B "")  -- True
```

Comment: `@"A"` is a [visible type application](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#visible-type-application), where the argument being applied to is a [type-level string literal](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#type-level-literals)  `"A"`. Here's a tutorial for GHC generics https://generics-eot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and the internals of the generic-lens library are described in their paper https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=3243631.3236780

Comment: There's way too much to explain from scratch to fit in a SO answer, but at least you know there's something out there.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with a simple fold? If you need something more general then imo more motivation is required.

```
data D = A Int | B String | C Bool Char    

f :: [D] -> Bool
f = foldr f' False
  where f' (B _)   _ = True
        f' (C _ _) _ = False
        f' _       b = b
```

Comment: Well, this fold would only improve if you had a _"constructor predicate"_ at hand already. But actually, a fold is such a general device I would usually go to some length to avoid it: more general a device — more space for a programmer to make a mistake.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment, but I'm not sure you're going to get more readable than this. If you have access to predicates then something like `maybe False isB . listToMaybe . filter ((||) <$> isB <*> isC)` works but is it really better?..

Comment: Well, I do have something like this in mind: `\xs -> let preds = [isB, isC] in fmap minimum . mconcat . (fmap . fmap) pure $ ($ xs) <$> preds`.